# Adding a for-statement to the content_tag() method in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, content-tag

This is what I want to build in Ruby on Rails:

```
<tr>
<td>attribute0</td>
<input name="1" type="radio" value="1" />
<input name="1" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="1" type="radio" value="3" />
<input name="1" type="radio" value="4" />
<input name="1" type="radio" value="5" />
<td>attribute1</td>
</tr>
```

the number of the radio buttons should be variable.
I'm using the content_tag method to generate the HTML-tags:

```
@template.content_tag(:tr, @template.content_tag(:td, ... ))
```

Is it possible to add statement like

```
for i in 1..5 do
    @template.tag(:input, :type => 'radio', :value => i, :name => options[:name])
end
```

as a parameter for content_tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a block or use a helper. Here's an example of a helper method

```
def inputs(amount, name)
  [1..amount].inject('') do |html, num| 
    html + tag(:input, type: 'radio', value: num, name: name)
  end
end
```

Edit: exmaple of block

Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

```
content_tag :ul do
  5.times.map{ content_tag :li, 'element' }.reduce(&:+)
end

# same as

elements = 5.times.map{ content_tag :li, 'element' }.reduce(&:+)
content_tag :ul, elements
```